# What are the side effects of parsing JS files as PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, embedding

I have some php variables that need to be used in javascript. Instead of passing vars back and forth using ajax, I chose to parse js files as php. Here's a simple example of what I did:

```
#.htaccess
AddType application/x-httpd-php .js

//scripts.js
//or for security reason, I could just use scripts.php and add header at the top)

header("Content-type: text/javascript");
alert("Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>");
```

I'v been using this method for a while, and I haven't noticed any obvious problems.

Are there any side effects doing things this way? Thanks.

Comment: You'd probably want to do this for a custom extension like `.phpjs` to avoid doing this on every single JavaScript file.

Comment: @tadman aha, guess what, that's the extension I'm using now. To make the example simple enough, I changed to js.

Comment: You also have the side effect that if the js is cached, and another user logs into the same machine, they would likely be served the wrong js.

Comment: Not to mention, increased server load.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problem with this, but an easier solution for me was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var username = "<?=$_SESSION["username"]?>";
</script>
```

in the head-Zone of the template or index.